# Why does running phpunit not run vendor/bin/phpunit?

Tags: laravel, phpunit

I am having a weird issue,
when I run

```
$ phpunit
```

I get

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method PHPUnit_Framework_TestResult::warningCount() in /home/vagrant/.composer/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/TextUI/ResultPrinter.php on line 185

Call Stack:
    0.0009     231392   1. {main}() /home/vagrant/.composer/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit:0
    0.0065     743872   2. PHPUnit_TextUI_Command::main() /home/vagrant/.composer/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit:47
    0.0066     744512   3. PHPUnit_TextUI_Command->run() /home/vagrant/.composer/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/TextUI/Command.php:106
    1.1720    6818904   4. PHPUnit_TextUI_TestRunner->doRun() /home/vagrant/.composer/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/TextUI/Command.php:155
    1.4597   16188088   5. PHPUnit_TextUI_ResultPrinter->printResult() /vagrant/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/TextUI/TestRunner.php:446
```

However, when I run

```
$ ./vendor/bin/phpunit
```

it works as expected and runs my tests.

Maybe I have another program or something that is using the phpunit alias or something?

How can I debug to find that out?
Any ideas?

Comment: What output do you get when run `which phpunit` in console?

Comment: Fatal error: Call to undefined method PHPUnit_Framework_TestResult::warningCount........ like i wrote in my questing

Comment: Please read again the @UshakovNikita comment. Looks like you have PHPUnit installed globally. When you execute `phpunit` directly, the global installation is being used, and that one fails.

Comment: @UshakovNikita sorry i did not see that: /home/vagrant/.composer/vendor/bin/phpunit

Comment: how do i uninstall it globally?

Comment: I recommend to keep global phpunit and make alias with `alias pu="php vendor/bin/phpunit"` so you will be able run `pu` instead of `phpunit` when you want project specific phpunit instance. With this you will always be able to run global phpunit when you don't have it in `vendor/bin`

Comment: @NikitaU. if he's using vagrant, there's no reason to do that, right? Typically it's one project per VM.

Answer (score 3):

Assume you had installed `phpunit` from `composer.json` of current Laravel App.

Run this:
`vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit`

Because the global one might be incompatible version of phpunit. Which is called and execute in the current package.

Answer (score 1):

On windows I have an incompatible version installed globally.

To workaround, create "phpunit.bat" in root of project with contents:

```
"vendor/bin/phpunit"
```

This takes precendece over the phpunit in the system path.

Answer (score 1):

How did you configure adding /vendor/bin to path?

I have this in my `~/.bashrc` file:

`PATH="$PATH:/path/to/vendor/bin"`

This adds /vendor/bin/ to the **end of your path**, so if there is any other executable called phpunit earlier in your path - in your case, the globally installed one - it will be called instead.

To fix this, add `vendor/bin` to the **beginning** of your path in `~/.bashrc`:

`PATH="/path/to/vendor/bin:$PATH"`

Then log out and log in or run `source ~/.bashrc`, and the system should then find `/vendor/bin/phpunit` first when you run`phpunit`.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows, you can set an enviroment variable in your project's root directory.

Type this in your console/terminal:

```
set phpunit=vendor/bin/phpunit
```

I had the same problem with Laravel and PhpStorm, and after i typed this in my **PhpStorm terminal**, the problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

I've just found about about `doskeys` for Windows. I think they are called aliases on Mac, but they allow you to create a command as an alias for another command.

This way, I can use:

```
doskey macroName=macroDefinition
```

which in my case is:

```
doskey p=.\vendor\bin\phpunit
```

which then means I can just use the command `p` from my project folder for phpunit - much quicker!

For example I can now use the command:

```
p --filter my_single_test tests/MyExampleTest.php
```